# AFNetworking download progress issue iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, afnetworking-2

I am using following code in order to download zip file using following code with only one running operation at a time

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:TempUrl]];
    operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.zip",model.iD]];
    operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];
    [operation setUserInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:model forKey:@"model"]];

    [operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSUInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpectedToRead) {

        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)bytesRead);
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)totalBytesRead);
        NSLog(@"%lu",(unsigned long)totalBytesExpectedToRead);
}];
```

Following code handles pausing and resuming download on app home button press or screen lock

```
// Notification invokes these methods
-(void)appEntersBg {  // Application enters background

    if([[self downloadQueue] operationCount]) {

        [[[[self downloadQueue]operations]firstObject] pause];

    }}

-(void)appEntersForground {  // application enters forground

    if([[self downloadQueue] operationCount]) {

        [[[[self downloadQueue]operations]firstObject] resume];

    }
}
```

When I start a download i get proper values in bytes read and bytes expected
but weird values when app enters Background and then again enters forground.

Like I am downloading a file of size 10MB

I start download and DOWNLOADEDSIZE reaches 4MB. 
and EXPECTEDDOWNLOADSIZE size is 10MB

Now I press home button and downloading PAUSES.
Launch app
App Enters Forground and downloading RESUMES

Now EXPECTEDDOWNLOADSIZE is 6MB (10-4MB)
and DOWNLOADEDSIZE is same as previous 4MB.

File is downloaded properly but How will I show the download progress correctly after
multiple times app getting into background and foreground

Any suggestions or help

I am working on iOS 7 and AFNetworking 2.

Comment: hi... i am facing the same issue toooo, any help plzzz